# How not to mess up a customers SQL database?

Tags: sql-server, security, backup, frontend

Next week I will create some simple select queries for PowerBI for a new customer who wants to have more insight in his business.

Until now I have only done this for our own company. I am afraid that by installing SQL Server Management Studio and building some queries in Management Studio I might (in a freak accident scenario) damage his database. I know this is unlikely.

However I do not really want to mess with his configuration. I also do not want to give him any ground to argument against me if anything unrelated does not work afterwards.

What would be a reasonable way to get my queries without really touching his database ? I thought of using a 3rd party frontend like Heidi SQL or FlySpeed SQL (even better because you cannot do admin tasks with it). I cannot just start with PowerBI because I need to analyze his DB first (scroll through tables etc).

Also I thought of making a backup of his DB first but that involves playing around with Management Studio.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Simple: **work on a restored backup copy!** Never ***EVER*** work **directly** on a customer's production data!! NOT EVER -----

Comment: You do not have to use SQL management studio, but any query editor such as SSRS tools by using report builder or Visual Studio instead.

Comment: Okay, so I could create a backup. Then I would have to restore it each time I want new data. Do you think it is dangerous to just view data and make a few select statements with SSRS or FlySpeed ? I mean what could go wrong ? Heidi SQL might be to dangerous because it is a real frontend. But in FlySpeed I can analyze relationships but I cannot alter DB settings.

Comment: Another possibility would be to create a datareader user and only login as him....?

Comment: Before doing anything, backup the data to a few thumb drives.   Ship one of them to a sealed underground vault in Switzerland.   @marc_s How bad did you screw up the data? :)

Comment: As long as I never type update, alter, insert or delete in a query editor (not admin frontend) I should be safe, right ? I will discuss backups with my client before.

Comment: @SteveWellens: dropped three tables from a running production system ..... at 4pm in the afternoon .... worked til past midnight to restore the system ......

Comment: @KurtKoala: that's what I thought too...... but it just happens, you're in the middle of doing something, and then: "oh,I need to delete that row" and BAM! the table is gone. Just ***NEVER EVER*** work directly on production system + data - especially if you're "playing around trying something out" - ***NEVER EVER***. Period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [SSMS ToolsPack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/). It wont stop you from updating/deleting some rows. But will give you a warning if you are running a update/delete without a where clause. Or if you run a TRUNCATE or DROP TABLE statement. See config for settings. Also has color coding for windows.

Also has Window connection coloring - you can color the query windows based on the server/database name

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Backup and restore. Then use the backup to work as a development system that way you can work out the bugs then put your app or queries into production.